# Jquery validation on div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am extending the functionality of a Business Intelligence tool. This is a web based application. Currently attempting to create some type of "form" validation. The strange thing is that this application reuses the same input for every single one of the form inputs. Once the user clicks away from the input html object, some javascript moves the value entered into the input into the text within a div.

**Before**:

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Input **filled out**:

```html
<input type="text" value="this is a test">
```

**Result**:

```html
<div>
this is a test>
</div>
```

Is there any way to create a listener which will validate what is written inside of the div?

Comment: NO NO NO !!!

Before must discovery HTML!!!

<input type=text>this is a test</input> instead <input type="text" value="this is a test">

Comment: Why don't you validate the input instead?

Comment: I may be able to do that. But the page may have 10 divs which are considered "input". And the actual input tag is reused for all of them for some reason...

Comment: Why the hell did they used just one input?

Comment: I have no clue..... their developers always do weird things

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" value="this is a test"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type=text value=this is a test></input>
```

hope this helps...

Comment: thanks, I wrote that psudo code real quick. Thanks for the information, but I think that willnot help.